# Enabling clean URLs (Drupal 7) in .htaccess on Debian

Tags: content-management-system, drupal-7, debian, clean-urls

I am having a complicated issue, which I can't figure out. There is a solution to this matter by modifying the **000-default** file in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled**.

The **AllOverride** line must be left with the following keyword **None**.

`<Directory /var/www/>

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny

    allow from all

</Directory>`

Is there any other way to enable clean URLs on a Debian server for Drupal 7?

Comment: Not sure how this would be different to normal. Have you done this on other sites before?

Comment: I had my site running on a different server, with a different version of Apache (Debian), clean URL worked, even without modifying the 000-default file or .htaccess. I tried many .htaccess tweaks, no results though. An effective way to resolve this issue by many users is to modify the 000-default file. Unfortunately, I have no persmission to do that, and the server is hosting many sites so this option is unacceptable. So I'm looking for a different solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the rewrite base?

Comment: I tried that too, but I made a basic mistake. I just found out that my .htaccess file is being ignored, in other words, it's not even being used. The only way now is to contact the server admin.

Comment: Ah ok. If you need help afterwards edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your .htaccess file in your project root. 
Uncomment `RewriteBase /drupal` and change it to your project name like `RewriteBase /myprojectname` .
Comment `RewriteBase /`
Goto /admin/config/search/clean-urls
There will be an option to Enable clean URLs .